# Subset a dataframe based on a column that has two attributes

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Say I have a dataframe

```
ds <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="
                 g1 color
                 A red
                 A yellow
                 B red
                 C red
                 C yellow
                 ")
```

so what I want subset a new dataframe that only contains groups in g1 that has both "red" and "yellow" in column color. The new table using the example above would not have any rows containing B.  I'm not sure how to approach this since sub-setting with red or yellow would still contain "B" which only has red.

```
ds[ds$color=="red" | ds$color=="yellow", ]
```

thanks.

Comment: Your example is not about `data.table`. Are you searching for a solution with `data.frame` or with `data.table`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for.  maybe you could give the desired output?

Comment: @Puddlebunk OP says group B would be excluded based on their criteria; other than dropping those rows, the table will be the same, I guess.

Comment: Re data.table, there's an open issue regarding nicer syntax for this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788 For now... `setDT(ds)[, if (all(c("red","yellow") %in% color)) .SD, by=g1]`

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` you can use a simple `group_by()` and `filter()`:

```
ds %>% group_by(g1) %>% filter(all(c("red","yellow") %in% color))
```

This will allow for any number of values you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
ds$col.count <- ave(as.integer(ds$color), ds$g1, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
ds[ds$col.count==2,]
```

A short variant is:

```
ds[as.logical(ave(as.integer(ds$color), ds$g1, FUN=function(x) 2==length(unique(x)))), ]
```

the `as.integer()` is needed because `ave()` works on a numeric vector, the `as.logical()` is needed because the result of `ave()` is a numeric vector.

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
ds <- fread(header = TRUE, 
"g1 color
 A red
 A yellow
 B red
 C red
 C yellow")
ds[, col.count:=length(unique(color)), by=g1][col.count==2]
```

If it is clear that in every group each color can't be twice then you can simply do:

```
ds[, col.count := .N, by = g1][col.count == 2]
```

Comment: The solution from Franks comment to the question is very nice!

Comment: Hope you don't mind I've edited your answer

Comment: @UweBlock It is not the same, e.g. if there is a extra row `A red`. It is only the same if it is clear that in every group each color can't be twice.

Comment: Good point, overlooked this. Thanks for rectifying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lengthy base R method with `ave`

```
ds[as.logical(ave(as.character(ds$color), ds$g1, 
                  FUN=function(i) "red" %in% i & "yellow" %in% i)), ]
  g1  color
1  A    red
2  A yellow
4  C    red
5  C yellow
```